# Adding items to ComboBox wpf which are always the same collection?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a combobox declared in my xaml.
I have a `ExtendedComboBoxItem : ComboBoxItem` defined which has properties DisplayName and DisplayImage.

In my user control, I have a comboBox control where i defined a data template that is essentially a `Image | TextBock`

In code-behind, I ALWAYS ADD same 3 items to it, so I do something like:

```
List<ExtendedComboBoxItem > items = new List<ExtendedComboBoxItem >();
ExtendedComboBoxItem item1 = new ExtendedComboBoxItem ("A","imagePath");
ExtendedComboBoxItem item2 = new ExtendedComboBoxItem ("A","imagePath");
ExtendedComboBoxItem item3 = new ExtendedComboBoxItem ("A","imagePath");
items.Add(item1);
items.Add(item2);
items.Add(item3);
this.comboBox.ItemsSource = items;
```

Is there a XAML only way of doing the above or a better cleaner way to do this?
thanks!

Comment: "I have a ExtendedComboBoxItem : ComboBoxItem defined which has properties DisplayName and DisplayImage". This is the wrong approach. Use a view model and a DataTemplate instead. See the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article on MSDN. Then take a look at the answer given by Ayyappan. You should however not set the ItemsSource property on code, but instead bind it to a view model property of type ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that this will work - there are some ifs and buts regarding the type you can put in the array: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753379%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Requirements_for_a_Custom_Class_as_a_XAML_Element .

You can set up an array in the Resources section of your XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <x:Array Type="mynamespace:ExtendedComboBoxItem"  
             x:Key="MyArray">
        <mynamespace:ExtendedComboBoxItem MyProp1="A" MyProp2="imagePath" />
        <mynamespace:ExtendedComboBoxItem MyProp1="A" MyProp2="imagePath" />
        <mynamespace:ExtendedComboBoxItem MyProp1="A" MyProp2="imagePath" />
    </x:Array>

</Window.Resources>

...

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyArray}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a DataTemplate for the Items in the combobox, Refer below code.

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cbo">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding DisplayImage}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableCollection<ComboItem> combolst = new ObservableCollection<ComboItem>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                combolst.Add(new ComboItem() { DisplayName = "Name" + i, DisplayImage = "Icon.png" });
            }
            cbo.ItemsSource = combolst;
        }       
    }

    public class ComboItem
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string DisplayImage { get; set; }

    }
```